# ImageMagick on high sierra causes weird issues with minimagick rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, imagemagick, macos-high-sierra, minimagick

So I am TRYING to use my macbook pro I bught and use that for my development of a website that's been done predominately on Ubuntu on a really old Lenovo laptop. On my mac I have high sierra and I installed imagemagick with homebrew, however my images on my blog on the local server are way out of proportion and aren't scaling the way minimagick tells them too, so my rss feed looks a mess, even though it looks perfectly normal with the same code on my linux. Any suggestions?

Gemfile

```
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'fog'
```

image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :fog

  process resize_to_fit: [300,300]

  version :medium do

      # change the word 'fit' to 'fill'
      process resize_to_fill: [400,400]
  end

  version :large do
    process resize_to_fill: [1000,1000]
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

model:

```
class HomeBlog < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  has_many :hashtaggings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :hashtags, through: :hashtaggings, dependent: :destroy

  acts_as_votable

  def next
    self.class.where("id > ?", id).first
  end

  def previous
    self.class.where("id < ?", id).last
  end

  def last
    self.class.where("id = ?", id).last
  end

  def self.highest_voted
     self.order("cached_votes_total DESC")
  end

  def all_hashes=(names)
    self.hashtags = names.split(",").map do |name|
      Hashtag.where(name: name.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end

  def all_hashes
    self.hashtags.map(&:name).join(", ")
  end
end
```

controller:

```
class HomeBlogsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:upvote, :downvote]
before_action :set_home_blog, only: [:show, :upvote, :downvote]

  # GET /home_blogs
  # GET /home_blogs.json
  def index
  end

  def rss_feed
    @home_blogs = HomeBlog.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
    @highest_voted = HomeBlog.highest_voted.first
  end

  # GET /home_blogs/1
  # GET /home_blogs/1.json
  def show
    @home_blog = HomeBlog.find(params[:id])
    @next_home_blog = @home_blog.next
    @previous = @home_blog.previous
  end

  # GET /home_blogs/new
  def new
    @home_blog = HomeBlog.new
  end

  # GET /home_blogs/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /home_blogs
  # POST /home_blogs.json


  def upvote
    @home_blog.upvote_from current_user
    redirect_to request.referrer
    flash[:success] = "thanks for the vote"
  end

  def downvote
    @home_blog.downvote_from current_user
    redirect_to request.referrer
    flash[:success] = "thanks for the vote"
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /home_blogs/1
  # PATCH/PUT /home_blogs/1.json


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_home_blog
      @home_blog = HomeBlog.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def home_blog_params
      params.require(:home_blog).permit(:name, :entry, :image)
    end

end
```

appplication.scss

```
  #rss-feed-div {
        margin-top: 150px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #2C2C7C;
        padding: 2px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 5px;
        border-color: #95A5A6;
        border-style: solid;
        position: relative;
        h1 {
          color: white;
        }
      }

      .cover-photo {
        width: 50%;
        max-width: 400px;
        min-width: 150px;
        max-height: 400px;
        min-height: 200px;
        float: left;
        border: 5px;
        border-color: #95A5A6;
        border-style: solid;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);

      }
      .blog_post_content {
        width: 80%;
        margin-left: 20%;
        height: 76%;
        min-height: 400px;
        min-width: 400px;
        max-width: 800px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        background-color: #2C2C7C;
        border: 5px;
        border-color: #95A5A6;
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        .post-title{
          background-color: #8E8A89;
          font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 30px;
          width: 50%;
          float: right;
          margin-bottom: 30px;
          padding: 5px;

        }
        .post-text {
          background-color: white;
          font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
          padding-bottom: 10px;
          float: right;
          width: 50%;
          padding: 4px;
          p {
            font-size: 15px;
          }
          a {
            font-size: 20px;
          }
        }
      }
      .hashtags {
        background-color: #8E8A89;
        border-top: 5px;
        border-color: #95A5A6;
        border-style: solid;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 1%;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }
      .pagination {
        margin-left: 25px;
        background-color: white;
        border: 2px;
        border-style: groove;
        border-color: black;
        background-color: #8E8A89;
        a {
          color: black;
          font-size: 20px;
        }
      }
```

rss_feed.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  <div id="rss-feed-div"><h1><%= image_tag("icons8-rss-40.png") %>RSS Feed</h1></div>
  <% if @highest_voted %>
    <div id="most-popular">
      <h4><b>#Trending</b></h4>
      <%= link_to @highest_voted.name, @highest_voted %>
      <%= image_tag @highest_voted.image.to_s %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="pagination"><%= will_paginate @home_blogs %></div>


        <% @home_blogs.each do |p| %>






            <div class="blog_post_content">
              <div class="cover-photo">
                <%= image_tag p.image_url(:medium).to_s %>
              </div>
              <div class="post-title"><b><%= p.name %> | <%= p.created_at.to_date %></b></div>

              <% if p.entry.length > 200 %>
                  <div class="post-text">
                  <p><%=  truncate(p.entry, :ommision => "... Read More", :length => 200, escape: false) %></p>
                  <%= link_to "Read more", p %><%= image_tag "icons8-chevron-right-24.png" %>
                  </div>
              <div class="hashtags"><%= image_tag("if__hashtag_2559811.png", style: 'height:50px;width:50px;')%><b><%= p.all_hashes %></b></div>
            </div>
            <br />

            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        <br />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest you check the HTML code and/or andy CSS style sheet to see what is being defined for styling. You might post some of the code where the images are defined.

Comment: Is there any other file you'd like to see? Just added my code, thanks

Comment: I'm not much of a deisgner, really, AT ALL, but my code shouldn't cause the images to do what they're doing on my mac

Comment: Check your browsers to see if they are set up differently with regard to zoom, scaling and default density.

Comment: yeah nothing works. I think it has to do with the version of ImageMagick I have on High Sierra. Ubuntu doesn't need that program for the rails image processor to do its thing in localhost.

Comment: I am on a Mac Sierra and have never seen anything like that happen. But I install my delegates from MacPorts and then compile Imagemagick from source. Have you tried installing and testing the current versions of IM 7 and IM 6. If so, do both fail? What is your version of Imagemagick and how did you install that? What image type are trying to convert from and to? Do you have current delegates for them in your IM versions of both systems? Are the IM versions the same on both systems? Sorry,  I am not that familiar with carrier wave or mini-magic.